# Buck converter with state feedback: does changing the input voltage changes the dynamic of the converter?

Tags: buck, control-system, feedback

**Short question:** in a buck converter with state feedback, do changes in the input voltage cause changes in the dynamics of the output voltage (and inductor current)?

**The problem:** let's say we have a buck converter, for which we can consider the average model for analysis purposes. Also, let's consider that the duty cycle is 0.5. In the open-loop circuit, if we apply a step change in the input voltage, the output voltage will show some dynamics and will settle at some value. In this case, the dynamics will be the same regardless of the magnitude of the step change, whether it is 1 V or 10 V. The behavior of the output voltage will only scale in magnitude with the step change, but its shape will not change. So basically, the model of the circuit does not depend on the input voltage, we just need to scale the output accordingly.

Now, let's consider that we will add a state feedback controller to the system. We will choose the gain vector \$K\$ so that the poles of the system are placed at a certain location in order to have a certain dynamic response.

**The question** now is: if the input voltage changes, will the output voltage keep the dynamics and only scale with changes of input voltage? Can we keep the model independent of the input voltage?

I believe that this is not the case, and changing the input voltage now will actually change the dynamics of the system, and the model of the system cannot be independent of the input voltage anymore. This is in contrast with the open-loop system, where we can remove the dependence of the input voltage.

**My reasoning** is the following. Consider the (average) model of the buck converter on the state-space representation

$$
\begin{bmatrix} \dot{i_L} \\ \dot{v_C}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1/L \\ 1/C & -1/RC\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} i_L \\ v_C\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} V_i/L \\ 0\end{bmatrix}u
$$
where \$R\$, \$L\$ and \$C\$ are the load, inductor and capacitor of the converter, \$i_L\$ is the inductor current, \$v_C\$ is the capacitor voltage, \$V_i\$ is the input voltage and \$u\$ is the duty cycle. Considering the usual state space representation of the form

$$
\dot{x} = Ax + Bu
$$
and if we choose a state feedback law of the form \$u = -Kx + r\$, with \$r\$ the reference, then the closed-loop system becomes
$$
\dot{x} = (A-BK)x + Br.
$$
We choose the vector \$K\$ to place the poles at a desired location. Now, for me, if we change the input voltage \$V_i\$, then we will be changing the matrix \$(A - BK)\$, and that will change the dynamics of the system; the response will not be merely scaled by changes in \$V_i\$.

I discussed this issue with a colleague, and he told me that \$V_i\$ should not be a part of the matrix \$B\$, and so changing \$V_i\$ will not change the dynamics of the system but will only scale its response. But to me, it is not possible to simply remove \$V_i\$ from the matrix \$B\$, because doing so would cause the feedback law to change to
$$
V_iu = -Kx.
$$
Now, if \$V_i\$ changes, the control law will not be exactly \$-Kx\$ anymore, and that will essentially change \$K\$, which will again impact the matrix \$(A - BK)\$.

The implication of this is that, if we design static gains (pole placement, LQR), these gains will not give the desired response anymore if \$V_i\$ changes. On the other hand, I believe these gains will just scale with changes in \$V_i\$, but then we have to measure this voltage.

Are there any flaws on my reasoning?